# Is it possible to skip make test during brew install?

Tags: homebrew

Sometimes `brew install` takes very long (in hours) in the `make test` step. Is it possible to install a formula while skipping tests?

I understand this is risky but it may have its uses. For example, you may know that the formula version should work fine in your system and do not want to run the tests. Or you may have executed the tests already separately and do not want to run them again during install...

---

For example installing `perl`:

```
$ brew install perl


==> Downloading https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.28.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/$USER/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/45e6e5b74854dc24d37224b5ad14fd66b3f9520235c1e1ff5b8decb20e22b755--perl-5.28.1.tar.gz
==> ./Configure -des -Dprefix=/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1 -Dprivlib=/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1 -Dsitelib=/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.1 -Dotherlibdirs=/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.1 -
==> make
==> make test
```

Looking at the processes, it is iterating over the majority of `*.t` files in perl repo.

```
\-+- 24088 $USER /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make test
 \-+- 26674 $USER /bin/sh -e ./runtests choose
   \-+- 26679 $USER ./perl TEST
     \-+- 43493 $USER ./perl -I.. -MTestInit=U1 ../lib/warnings.t
       \-+- 48110 $USER sh -c /private/tmp/perl-20190416-7230-1i4txcx/perl-5.28.1/perl -I../../lib  "tmp43493C" </dev/null 2>&1
         \--- 48111 $USER /private/tmp/perl-20190416-7230-1i4txcx/perl-5.28.1/perl -I../../lib tmp43493C
```

---

`brew install` help does not mention anything about skipping tests.

```
$ brew install --help  | grep test
        --include-test               Install testing dependencies required to
                                     run brew test.
```

---

**Update**

I guess I could remove the

`system "make", "test"`

[line](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/3471ec3cf71afa36b328c1a40022cff4715e4ec5/Formula/perl.rb#L47) from perl's (or any formula's) formula file.

Then, I think I need to invoke brew like:

```
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install …
```

HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE docs: [LINK](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/7d31a70373edae4d8e78d91a4cbc05324bebc3ba/Library/Homebrew/manpages/brew.1.md.erb#L202)

Comment: Your suggestion to edit the formula just saved my day, thank you! If you ever return to this question, you should submit and mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Nope. The way the `perl` formula is written, that `make test` is just part of the main install process, and there's no option to turn it off.

You'll need to just edit the formula or create your own custom alternate formula if you want to turn it off.